# Ruby - retry function with different params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, retry-logic

I'd like to retry a function with different params depending on the result of the first iteration:

Giving a retry function like follow:

```rb
 def retry_on_fail(**args)
   yield
 rescue StandardError => e
    args = args.merge(different_param => true) if e.class == `specific_error`
    retry
```

Is there a way to do so? I didn't find it yet...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can yield however many times you want in a method and the trick is really passing the arguments to the block:

```
# given
class SpecificError < StandardError; end

def retry_on_fail(**args)
  yield(args)
rescue SpecificError 
  yield(args.merge(different_param: true))
end
```

```
retry_on_fail do |args|
  raise SpecificError if args.empty?
  args
end
# returns { different_param: true }
```

There is also a slight differnce here flow wise - `retry` runs the whole method from the top and this will just call the block again. If thats what you want you could do:

```
def retry_on_fail(**args)
  yield(args)
rescue SpecificError 
  args.merge!(different_param: true) 
  retry
end
```

But this has the potential to create an endless loop if the block raises the same exception again.

Comment: Note that I intentionally avoided `rescue StandardError` as thats a prime example of Pokémon exception handling. Only rescue exceptions that you know what to do with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def retry_on_fail(**args)
  rescue_args = args 
  begin
    yield(rescue_args)
  rescue StandardError => e
    rescue_args = rescue_args.merge(different_param => true) if e.class == `specific_error`
    retry
  end  
end
```